# How can I build a regex for (potentially Polish) words with at least four capital letters?

Tags: c#, regex

I have this line of code:

```
var Stops3Original = 
           Regex.Matches(Timetable, @"[A-ĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ]{4,}").Cast<Match>().ToList();
```

And it doesn't work (it pass "przejazd", for example). I want to get only words with a minimum of four capital letters (they can have Polish letters like ą,ę). How might I do this?

Comment: Do you want to match consecutive  4 capital letters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were nearly there. You want

```
[A-ZĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ]{4,}
```

- Your regex contained `A-Ą`, which allowed all letters in the Unicode range U+0041 to U+0104, which includes all lower-case letters
- `A-Z` matches all caps in the range from `A` to `Z`
- The other letters are the nine additional Polish capital letters

---

**Reference**

[Polish code pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_code_pages)